# No Color Showing in TikZ Drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I am trying to draw some pictures using TikZ within LaTeX. I have started by using simple examples, but I am having trouble getting colors to show. For example, I use the following commands, but only get black and white output for the items created with TikZ. As suggested, I am supplying a full, compilable document that generates the behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2] 
\draw [gray] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw [red] (0, 0.5) -- (2,0.5);
\draw [blue] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\textcolor{red}{this shows in red correctly}

\end{document}
```

I am using scientific workplace to create my document. I have used the `tikz` package, as well as the `color` and `xcolor` packages. Any thoughts as to why there is no color. I know the system is generally capable of creating color, as the second `\textcolor` statement comes out in red.

Comment: It would be great if you could turn your code into a full, compilable, minimal document that reproduces the described behaviour. You might be loading some packages that interfere with the colour.

Comment: This compiles fine (with color) for me. What compiler do you use (`pdflatex`?), and what viewer (Acrobat)?

Comment: By the way, `tikz` loads `xcolor`, so you don't need to load this explicitly yourself.

Comment: Tikz needs xcolor 2.00. You don"t need to load color because xcolor loads color. You can load xcolor if you need  some options like `\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}` but it's possible and preferable to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}   ` and finally you code compiles very well !

Comment: Compiles for me too using Pdflatex with TeXLive 2011. Also, for the above example, ONLY the `tikz` package is required to be explicitly loaded.

Comment: Should this thread be closed/removed? Through revision (?) the question references using the proprietary [Scientific Workplace](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html) and a quick check shows the question is now posted on the company [forum](http://forum.mackichan.com/node/565). Since the posted example works fine, it seems to be a problem with a Scientific Workplace and not a LaTeX problem.

Comment: @Jake, I am using `pdflatex` as the compiler and have viewed the document in Adobe Acrobat and OS X Preview. This does seem to be an issue using LaTeX within Scientific Workplace. Can anyone that uses Scientific Workplace confirm that the code compiles correctly? I realize that many here may not use Scientific Workplace, so do let me know if Scientific Workplace questions are not allowed on this forum.

Comment: @stanford202: Interesting! You should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted, so other people stumbling across the same problem can find the answer more easily. It's also worth pointing out that this reliance on old TikZ/PGF versions is quite a serious drawback: The new version (2.1) includes many quite important features (such as left or right aligning text in nodes), and the recommendation to update to a current version is a very frequent one on this site.

Comment: I presume that you mean (in the update) "Scientific Workplace **does not** work with newer versions of `pgf`".  As Jake said, it would be good to post that as an answer rather than an update to the question.

Comment: As this is accumulating "votes to close", I've taken the liberty of posting the update as an answer (Community Wiki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, Scientific Workplace does not work with newer versions of `pgf`. So, you need to have an older version of `pgf` installed, e.g. v1.18, in order to use `tikz`.

See more here: http://forum.mackichan.com/node/565#comment-1200

---

(The above was added to the original answer by the original questioner.  I've taken the liberty of posting this as an answer (CW) as part of "house keeping".)

Comment: Just wanted to also mention that Scientific Workplace can be made to work with newer versions of pgf, but you must change the latex formatter from True Tex to something like MikTex.